# jQuery selector on variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript, so please bear with me. I am trying to perform an AJAX get request to retrieve my JSON file which contains track information is formatted like this:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Short Skirt, Long Jacket",
        "artist" : "Cake",
        "album" : "Comfort Eagle",
        "genre" : "Rock",
        "year" : 2001,
        "albumCoverURL" : "images/ComfortEagle.jpg",
        "bandWebsiteURL" : "http://www.cakemusic.com"
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

I am trying doing this with these two functions:

```
function loadJSON () 
{
    $.getJSON("lab4.json", updateHTML(result));
}

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("site").click(function () 
    {
        loadJSON();
    });
});
```

When the user clicks on the link with the id "site" I want to sent an asynchronous javascript call to retrieve my JSON file. Upon success it should call my updateHTML function here:

```
function updateHTML (result)
{
    var templateNode = document.getElementById("song-template").cloneNode(true);
    document.removeChild(getElementById("song-template"));

    $.each(result, function(i, song)
    {
        var songNode = templateNode.cloneNode(true);
    });
}
```

Now, here's where I'm stuck: Now that I have this cloned node, how do I use jQuery to fill out all of the fields in the HTML here:

```
<a id="site" href="#"><img id="coverart" src="noalbum.png" /></a>
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<h2 id="artist"></h2>
<h2 id="album"></h2>
<p id="date"></p>
<ul id="genres"></ul>
```

Normally, I would just go like:

```
$("site").attr("src","images/ComfortEagle.jpg");
```

But now I'm faced with two issues. One, how do I get the new url from my JSON object that I have read in as 'song', and two, how do I target the "site" id inside the node that I cloned before I add it back to the document's html? Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up from what Im seeing in your code. To select an element with jQuery using the id you do need to put a `#` in front of the id like `$("#site")`

Comment: you have a logic error here: `$.getJSON("lab4.json", updateHTML(result));` you're executing `updateHTML` too early.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. Too early?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the ID from your keys

```
$.each(dataObj, function(key, val) {
    //dataObj is your returned JSON
    if ($("#" + key).length)
        $("#" + key).val(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first, If you're going to use jquery, use jquery.

You can use th ejquery clone() method rather than the js cloneNode to accomplish this.

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ARhtq/)

I think this is what your trying to do to with a more jquery ish solution.

```
var song = [1,2,3,4];

var templateNode = $("#lala");
$.each(song, function(key, val){
   var songNode = templateNode.clone(true);
    songNode.children('span.yo').text(val);
    $('#wrap').append(songNode);
});
```

AS for the json parsing, on each iteration, you should be able to access the props like any other json, so in the each loop, just target a prop like:

```
song.albumCoverURL
```